# grab redirected url by using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to find where I'll be redirected at. So I tried to functions for this, but none of those are working properly.

the links is here. when you try to enter, you will be redirected:

https://lions-mansion.jp/MA141070/

so I tried use cURL,

```
function redirect1($url) { 
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $data = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL );
        curl_close($ch);

        return $data;
    }
```

and also this:

```
function redirect($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (preg_match('~Location: (.*)~i', $result, $match)) {
           $location = trim($match[1]);
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

But I couldn't find the redirected url.

Comment: Use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);`

Comment: not working... @VilasGalave

Comment: What do you mean "can't catch the redirected link"

Comment: I gave the link in the question. if you run that link u see the redirected url. I want to grab that url @shingo

Comment: Have you checked the redirected url in the browser? they are same.

Comment: did you run the link? because they are definately not. @shingo

Comment: Yes, they are same except the first slash. try without cookies.

Comment: I don't know what link you are running, but to be clear I update my question. and put the redirected link too. you can check it, it's not the same ... @shingo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this page does not use a redirect-scheme that libcurl understands (it uses a html [`<meta http-equiv="REFRESH"`-redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh), unsupported by libcurl), so libcurl can neither tell you where it is being redirected, nor can libcurl auto-follow the redirect (because libcurl does not understand it)

you need to parse out the redirect url yourself from the HTML, eg

```
function redirect1($url) { 
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($data);
        $xp=new DOMXPath($domd);
        // <META http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;URL=http://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp/branz/roppongi4/?iad=daikyo" />

        $location=$xp->query("//meta[@http-equiv='REFRESH']")->item(0)->getAttribute("content");
        // 0;URL=http://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp/branz/roppongi4/?iad=daikyo   
        $location=substr($location,stripos($location,'URL=')+4);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $location;
    }
    var_dump(redirect1('https://lions-mansion.jp/MA141070/'));
```

output:

```
C:\projects\misc>php re.php
string(57) "http://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp/branz/roppongi4/?iad=daikyo"
```

Answer (score 0):

If keep you `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true`, after executing the CURL command you can use this function call to get the redirect of effective URL:

```
$finalUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

Comment: which line do I need to insert this exactly?

Comment: this would work if it was a redirect scheme that curl understands, but that's not the case here, it uses a [html meta refresh redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) which curl does not understand, so he gotta parse out the redirect url himself.  (luckily PHP's built-in tools DOMDocument and DOMXPath makes it easy to parse HTML :)  )

Comment: @hanshenrik makes sense :)